# jQuery click event weird behavior

Tags: jquery

I have a list of buttons to make changes to a forum (each button containing an unique data-mod attribute value). I wrote a jquery script to handle the last clicked button and send its value to a php database handler via ajax, which also sends a custom alert confirmation whether the moderator really wants to do the action or not (if not, alert closes and nothing happens, else, callback function is called).

However, I'm experiencing a weird behavior with this script, which regards the fact that even though I cancel the confirmation, the next confirmed alert will fire the callback function depending on how many times I've clicked the buttons. What I want is the callback function being fired one time with the last confirmed action.

```
$(function() {
var btn;
// Custom callback function
function callback(clicked) {
    $("#result").append("<br/>").append(clicked);
}
// Custom alert function
var alert = {
   Check: function(fnc, clicked) {
      $("#alert").show();
      $("[data-alert=1]").click(function() {
        fnc(clicked);
        alert.Close();
      });
      $("[data-alert=0]").click(function() {
        alert.Close();
      });
    },
    Close: function() {
      $("#alert").hide();
      return false;
   }
};
// Custom button function
$("[data-mod]").click(function() {
   btn = $(this);
   return alert.Check(callback, btn.data("mod"));
})
});
```

If description of the error wasn't clear enough, I've wrote a simplified fiddle so you can make changes at the code: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fq2mmzfq/).

Also, if the error seems a little bit confusing, here's a picture of the reproduction:
[I want only the last clicked button with the "Yes" confirmation button pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW3Sk.gif)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the Yes and No button displayed on the alert for your different buttons are the same every time.

So everytime the window pops up you bind a new click function to your yes button, and when you finally click it all the bound functions will trigger.

```
  //This code is called everytime a button is clicked, so your Yes and No
  //Button will execute as many callbacks when clicked.
  $("[data-alert=1]").click(function() {
    fnc(clicked);
    alert.Close();
  });
  $("[data-alert=0]").click(function() {
    alert.Close();
  });
```

As for the solution, just bind the click event to Yes or No once (not every time a button is clicked), store the last button clicked in a global variable (or whatever property or whatever element) and retrieve it in your callback function.

```
$(function() {
var btn;
// Custom callback function
function callback(clicked) {
    $("#result").append("<br/>").append(clicked);
}
// Custom alert function
var alert = {
   Check: function(fnc, clicked) {
      $("#alert").show();
      $("#alert").attr("last-clicked", clicked);
    },
    Close: function() {
      $("#alert").hide();
      return false;
   }
};

//Only called once
$("[data-alert=1]").click(function() {
  callback($("#alert").attr("last-clicked"));
  alert.Close();
});
$("[data-alert=0]").click(function() {
  alert.Close();
});

// Custom button function
$("[data-mod]").click(function() {
   btn = $(this);
   return alert.Check(callback, btn.data("mod"));
})
});
```

An alternative is to use `.off` to [remove all previous click bindings](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to your button, like such:

```
  $("[data-alert=1]").off("click").click(function() {
    fnc(clicked);
    alert.Close();
  });
```

But the downside is that it will remove all callbacks to the click events, even those that another part of the code could have put there. That's why maybe you're better off doing something like:

```
  $(document).on("click", "[data-alert=1]", function(...) {...});
```

Call this once and this will work even for dynamically created alert windows after this call.

Comment: I'm kinda confused. In a real world scenario, the alerts are dinamycaly loaded onto the page, with the load function (the template comes from an external file). On the other hand, I've updated the fiddle so it uses .one for the alert button clicks https://jsfiddle.net/fq2mmzfq/1/ still same error, could you modify the fiddle?

Comment: Another thing, since you've removed the function from inside the alert variable, the custom callback function is now only limited to callback(), which if I was going to reuse the alert for a different callback function, for instance somethingElse() it wouldn't work

Comment: @MateusMelo Yes, it all depends on the future and what you plan to do, and the different ways to do things are very broad. Anyway https://jsfiddle.net/fq2mmzfq/2/ (and the third code sample I give) don't have  the drawback you mentioned.

Comment: I think the third option will save me better since I don't have other code that could conflict with this approach. I'll mark this answer as the one to go, thank you sir, you've made my entire day of struggling so much better

Comment: And it was nice to see a question so nicely formatted :) If you later have a problem because of a conflict but still want to have the current flexibility, don't hesitate to post another question as there are ways to solve that as well (but it's better to have a specific problem to give the best answer).